# I have problem with Converting of WFS TO Featureclass

Tags: python-3.x, wfs

Can you tell me what is the problem with this WFS TO FEATURECLASS. i get this error: Fehler bei der Konvertierung von WFS in Feature Class: Fehler bei Ausführung. Parameter sind ungültig.
ERROR 000732: Eingabe-Features: Dataset Bodenrichtwerte_2023 ist nicht vorhanden oder wird nicht unterstützt.
Fehler beim Ausführen von (FeatureClassToFeatureClass).

```py
arcpy.conversion.WFSToFeatureClass(
        input_WFS_server="https://fbinter.stadt-berlin.de/fb/wfs/data/senstadt/s_brw_2023?REQUEST=GetCapabilities&SERVICE=wfs",
        WFS_feature_type="Bodenrichtwerte 01.01.2023",
        out_path=r"C:/TEMP/output.gdb",
        out_name="BRW_2023",
        is_complex="NOT_COMPLEX",
        max_features=1000,
        expose_metadata="DO_NOT_EXPOSE",
        swap_xy="DO_NOT_SWAP_XY",
        page_size=100
)
```

Comment: Please include in your question the reason *why* you're asking the question. Did you get any errors (and if so, which)? Is the behavior unexpected (if so, what did you expect and what did you see)?

Comment: BoppreH
i get this error. but i dont know why. wfs url is okay.